Existence of nonzero global section of dual of a locally free sheaf with a surjection
Let $X$ be a projective variety, and let $D$ is an effective divisor on $X$.
Suppose the map $\mathcal{E} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_D$ is a surjective map between sheaves of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules. Assumne further that $\mathcal{E}$ is locally free.
As we can consider a tensor product $\;\cdot\;\otimes\mathcal{O}_D$ is an right exact functor, we also get a surjection
$$
f:\mathcal{E}_{|D} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{D}
$$
between the sheaves as an $\mathcal{O}_{D}$-modules. Once I read from a literature, there is a statement that
$\textit{Since $\mathcal{E}$ is locally free, $\mathcal{E}_{|D}$ is also locally free. Hence $f$ induces a non-zero element of $\;\mathrm{H}^0(\mathcal{E}^{\vee}_{|D})$}$.
This may be true, but why the argument about the locall freeness of $\mathcal{E}$ is needed?
I think if a sequence of $\mathcal{O}_{D}$-modules $$\mathcal{E}_{|D}\rightarrow\mathcal{O}_{D}\rightarrow 0$$
is exact, takinig a functor $\mathcal{Hom}(-,\mathcal{O}_D)$ we have an exact sequence
$$
0 \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{D} \rightarrow \mathcal{E}^{\vee}_{|D} \rightarrow\cdots.
$$
Thus, we just have $\;\mathrm{H}^0(\mathcal{E}^{\vee}_{|D})\neq 0$ without the locally freeness assumption for $\mathcal{E}$.

In your last display you forgot to dualize the sheaf. And you are right, local freeness is not needed.

@Sasha Now I edit for the dualizing symbol as you said. Thank you for your answer.
